# iOS Drawing image issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing

I'm try to create application where I'm use a UIScrolView and I can draw different jpeg images on the appropriate point for each of this images. It is must looks like a video, for example:
I have a first jpeg image (background), and this image (for example image has coordinates: x = 0, y = 0, and dimentions: width = 1024, height = 768), I send to UIScrolView for showing. Then I get enother jpeg image with their own coordinatates and dimentions(for example x = 10, y = 10, width = 100, height = 100) and I need show this "smal" image over "background".
How I can di that?

Or another way of this issue. Example:
I have a BMP data of first image(bacground). How I can send this BMP data to the UIScrolView for showing?\

P.S. One more question: Which of presented above ways will run faster for processing and presentation of data?

WBR
Maxim Tartachnik

Comment: You want to create slide show?

Comment: Something like "slide show". I think it will be more like a video which will change some area of ​​the image.
I need to display over the main image change area.